# Uploading manifest from CCDI to CGC project

Tags: database, genomics, public-databases

Thank you in advance for your help!

I am trying to download data from the CCDI (Children Cancer Data Initiative) and I have a manifest csv file that I downloaded from the CCDI. I'm trying to upload this data to my CGC project, but there is not option to import data from manifest file from the CCDI specifically, and when I do try to upload it, only the manifest csv is added and not the files. What is the process for uploading manifest that are not from one of these databases?

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us (a lot) more context. What is this screenshot from? Where could we go to find it? Why are you using "import", is there no "upload" option? Do you have a [manifest file](https://support.illumina.com/help/BaseSpace_App_Enrichment_OLH_15050961/Content/Source/Informatics/Apps/ManifestFiles_swBS.htm) or a csv file? Can we see an example? What is CGC? Do you mean https://cgc.umn.edu/? Or maybe https://cancergenomics.org/? What would uploading these files actually do? What kind of data do you have?